# Setting text in footer on page and in header on next page

Tags: header-footer

The following tex file is trying to set a text (in this case a number, but it could be a string as well) in the footer of one page and the same value in the header on the following page. The idea is to set the value needed in the footer with each data item, then after each page update the header value for the following page.

The footer works ok, the header does not. The value in the header on the first page is ok, the value on the following pages are not.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\author{Bent Nielsen}
\title{page change testing}

\gdef\Total{0.00}
\gdef\TopTotal{0.00}

\afterpage{\gdef\TopTotal{\Total}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Top Total \TopTotal }
\rfoot{Current total \Total}

\begin{document}
Page 1
\gdef\Total{5.00}
\gdef\Total{10.00}
\gdef\Total{15.00}

\newpage

Page 2
\gdef\Total{20.00}
\gdef\Total{25.00}
\gdef\Total{30.00}

\newpage

Page 3
\gdef\Total{35.00}
\gdef\Total{40.00}
\gdef\Total{45.00}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\author{Bent Nielsen}
\title{page change testing}

\gdef\Total{0.00}
\gdef\TopTotal{0.00}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Top Total \TopTotal}
\rfoot{Current total \Total}

\newcommand{\mtTotal}[1]{%
\gdef\Total{#1}%
\afterpage{%
\gdef\TopTotal{#1}}}

\begin{document}
Page 1
\mtTotal{5.00}
\mtTotal{10.00}
\mtTotal{15.00}

\newpage

Page 2
\mtTotal{20.00}
\mtTotal{25.00}
\mtTotal{30.00}

\newpage

Page 3
\mtTotal{35.00}
\mtTotal{40.00}
\mtTotal{45.00}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. That works nicely. (I will wait a little for possible other answers before accepting).

Comment: @Bent but you can upvote anyway

Comment: I will when I can. Still too little rep I'm afraid. But definitely worth a +1.

Comment: @Bent welcome to Tex.sx